# Delphi TAction ShortCut doesn't work for child form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have An Action List (`actlst11`) on Form2, which is placed in run-time on `TTabSheet` of a Page Control from Main Form (like [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/a/bltip0305_5.htm)).

I added a Shortcut `Num +` for a `actZoomIn` Action from child Form2 (`actlst11`), but unfortunately it doesn't fire. Action is connected to Bit Button on Form2.

Any shortcut for actions from main form fires, any shortcut for child form placed inside Page-Control on Tab Sheet (Form2) doesn't fire.

What may be wrong and how I can forward shortcuts from Main to Child form or some work-arround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scenario you describe works as you hope in modern Delphi. A change was made in the implementation of `TCustomForm.IsShortCut`. Older Delphi implementations maintained a per-form list of action lists, and check that list in `IsShortCut`. That meant that only action lists associated with the top-level form were checked. In modern Delphi, the implementation of `IsShortCut` walks the ownership hierarchy. So long as the child form is ultimately owned by the top level form, then the child form's action lists will be located.

For you probably the easiest solution is to implement an event handler for the `OnShortcut` event of the top-level form. It would look like this:

```
procedure TTopLevelForm.FormShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := ChildForm.IsShortCut(Msg);
end;
```

If you have multiple child forms then you would want to walk over all of them giving each one in turn an opportunity to handle the shortcut. That might look like this:

```
procedure TTopLevelForm.FormShortCut(var Msg: TWMKey; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to FChildForms.Count-1 do
  begin
    Handled := FChildForms[i].IsShortCut(Msg);
    if Handled then
      exit;
  end;
end;
```

Obviously in this code you maintain `FChildForms`.

Or you could walk the ownership hierarchy if you want to implement the same solution as Embarcadero did.

Comment: Great! 
In my case maybe it's a little bit simpler - Since all my Child Forms are placed on Page Control TabSheets there may be only one active at the moment Child Form and no need to check for others.

Comment: Sure. Now you know the hook, you can work your code in around it.